Material UI multi-select component in React Hook Form
I am very new to React but I need to make a reusable multiselect drop down list to use inside a form.
I am trying to use ...register to handle the form data and errors, but this is not working.
(I also tried with setValue() both inside and outside the component but it doesn't work either).
When I have the "required" flag set as true then the validation doesn't pass even when I have a value selected, and even when I turn it off the "data.movies" is blank.
Form:
import top100Films from './films';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { useForm, FormProvider } from 'react-hook-form';
import MulitSelectAutoComplete from './MultiSelectAutocomplete'
const MyForm = () => {
  const form = useForm({

  });
  const { handleSubmit, formState, setValue } = form;
  const { errors } = formState;
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <FormProvider {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <MulitSelectAutoComplete
            options={top100Films}
            name={"movies"}
            label={'Best Movies'}
            required={true}
            onChange={(name, ids) => {
              // setValue(name, ids);
            }}
          />
          <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>

        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyForm;

Component:
import * as React from 'react';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';
import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxOutlineBlank';
import CheckBoxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/CheckBox';
import { useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

const icon = <CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon fontSize="small" />;
const checkedIcon = <CheckBoxIcon fontSize="small" />;

const MulitSelectAutoComplete = ({ options, name, label, required,  onChange }) => {
    const { register, formState: { errors }, setValue } = useFormContext();
    return (
        <>
            <label>{label} {required && "*"}</label>
            <Autocomplete
                multiple
                options={options}
                disableCloseOnSelect
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
                onChange={(event, value) => {
                    const ids = value.map((item) => item.year);
                    onChange(name, ids);
                    //setValue(name, ids);
                }}
                renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
                    <li {...props}>
                        <Checkbox
                            icon={icon}
                            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
                            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                            checked={selected}
                        />
                        {option.title}
                    </li>
                )}
                style={{ width: 500 }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                        {...params}
                        {...register(name, { required: required ? `${label} Required` : false })}
                        variant="standard"
                        error={!!errors[name]}
                        helperText={errors[name] && errors[name].message}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </>
    );
}
export default MulitSelectAutoComplete;

Like I said, I'm very new to React, so even if this is a stupid question please help me solve it

try using Controller from react-hook-form
